# warning: "MYClass may not respond to'-duration'. error: incompatible type for argument 1 of QTGetTimeInterval

Tags: objective-c

I just start learning Objective C and I found this code and want to understand it and get it to work. So I went through different documentations and I guess it doesn't work because NSTimeInterval is double and there is something wrong with types... but I don't understand 100% what is wrong and what I should do to get it work.

```
-(NSTimeInterval)
durationInSeconds 
{

        NSTimeInterval duration;
  QTGetTimeInterval([self duration], &duration);
        //here is warnning: "MYClass may not respond to '-duration'
 // here is error: incompatible type for argument 1 of QTGetTimeInterval
 return duration;
}
```

yes. thanks.

here is more code:

## import

## import

@interface MYAccessMp3Tags: NSObject
{
    NSTimeInterval duration;
    NSTimeInterval currentTime;
}

-(NSTimeInterval) durationInSeconds;
-(NSTimeInterval) currentTimeInSeconds;
-(NSDictionary *) metadata;
-(NSString *) metadataDescription;
-(NSString *) loadStateDescription;

@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval duration;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval currentTime;
@end

## import "MYAccessMp3Tags.h"

## import "NSString_FourCharCode.h"

## import

@implementation MYAccessMp3Tags;

@synthesize duration;
@synthesize currentTime;
-(NSTimeInterval)
durationInSeconds 
{

```
NSTimeInterval dur;

QTGetTimeInterval([self duration], &dur);

return duration;
```

}

-(NSTimeInterval)
currentTimeInSeconds 
{
    NSTimeInterval currTime;
    QTGetTimeInterval([self currentTime], &currTime);

```
return currentTime;
```

}

so i add @property & @sythesize. 
there is no warnings anymore but 
I still have errors: incompatible type for argument 1 of QTGetTimeInterval

Comment: This question needs more code or further explanation, as it's very unclear what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the getter for duration

add a property to your interface

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval duration;
```

and a synthesize to your implementation

```
@synthesize duration;
```

with `@property` and `@synthesize` the getter and setter are created for you.

and I would strongly recommend that you don't use the same names for local and instance variables.